# uitextfield animate width constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have this code to animate a width constraint of a UITextField

```
self.myTextFieldWidthConstraint.constant = 200
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.viewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

It works fine, the only issue is that if there is text inside the text field, during the animation it shrinks in character width and then re-adjusts to the correct size. The placeholder text does not have the same issue.

Here is a gif: http://makeagif.com/mr4u1D

Comment: Do you draw your text using drawrect?

Comment: I don't think that you can separate the animation of the text from the UITextField animation. Check this question for a workaround : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025624/fade-uitextfield-text

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, see http://makeagif.com/XZjc6u

Comment: @Thomas 2 conditions required to reproduce: Text in field and focus (first responder).

Answer (score 0):

Fahim, you can prevent the text scaling by resigning the first responder before you animate the width change, for example with:

```
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder]
```

or, more generally:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because field is already focused while doing the animation. My assumption is that you are doing your animation in:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
```

But you should do it instead in:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```